# Data Transformer on multiple fields and parent entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've been searching for a while, but was not able to find specific documentation on my `DataTransformer` use-case. Ofcourse there is [the Symfony2 cookbook chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), but it does not resolve my specific use-case. I could only find info on transforming a single field.

## Entities

I've got two entities (with a 0..n relationship)

#### Order

1. priceTotal (other fields aren't relevant)

#### OrderLine

1. amount
2. priceFactor
3. pricePerPiece
4. priceTotal

## Use-case

I do not want to calculate the `Order->priceTotal` on the fly in the view every time. That is why I'd like to create a transformer on the `OrderLine` that recalculates a couple of values on submit:

1. The `Order->priceTotal` should be a sum of all `OrderLine->priceTotal`
2. The `OrderLine->priceTotal` should be (`amount` * `priceFactor` * `pricePerPiece`)

Since I don't want to put this logic in every `Controller` function, I assume the `DataTransformer` is correct solution (?). Is the FormType the correct level for this type of validation?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think a DataTransformer is what you're looking for. A DataTransformer can mutate the submitted content for one field in your form, but does not have access to any fields around it. This is probably something you'll want to do with LifeCycleCallbacks.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-haslifecyclecallbacks

Here is an example of how LifeCycleCallbacks are used:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

It does not reflect what you want to do, but it will teach you what LifeCycleCallbacks are and how to use them.

Comment: `LifecycleCallbacks` indeed are the solution, since Doctrine ORM 2.4 it even is possible to access the `EventArgs`, so it is possible to add the parent entity to the `UnitOfWork`. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks-event-argument

The next problem is that Symfony has not adopted this new version of Doctrine ORM yet, as it still is on `~2.2`. https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/composer.json